# How do I put some space between the left side of a label and the beginning of the text?

Tags: ios, swift, uilabel, uiedgeinsets

How do I put some space between the left side of a label and the beginning of the text? I try to adjust the edge insets, but it is get only.

The code:

```
label.alignmentRectInsets = UIEdgeInsets(top: 2, left: 2, bottom: 2, right: 2)
```

Gets an error message:

> Cannot assign to property: 'alignmentRectInsets' is a get-only property

Comment: @dahiya_boy Is there a class for that?

Comment: Check this link it surely helps you.